# Continuous subtraction in Bigquery with Addition (For Inventory Planning)

Tags: sql, recursion

I have inventory(Pic 1) and future stock (pic 2):
[image]

[image]

I need this to get the below image:
I need is Recursive Inventory-Sales for each next day and for each sku until Arrival Date is matched and then I add stock to that number while keep deleting the sales. (If -ve then 0).

[image]

I have tried recursive function but it only works once since stock is a different table. Also I have tried iterative counters but when inventory becomes zero, then counter has to start again which is not possible

Can somebody suggest a solution for this in bigquery SQL?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query:

```
WITH recursive_cte AS (
  SELECT
    Items,
    Inventory,
    Transaction_date,
    Sale,
    LEAD(arrival_date) OVER (PARTITION BY Items ORDER BY transaction_date) as next_arrival_date,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Items ORDER BY transaction_date) as rn
  FROM
    inventory
),
cumulative_inventory AS (
  SELECT
    transaction_date,
    Items,
    Sale,
    inventory - SUM(Sale) OVER (PARTITION BY Items ORDER BY transaction_date) as cumulative_inventory,
    next_arrival_date,
    rn
  FROM
    recursive_cte
),
future_stock_adjusted AS (
  SELECT
    arrival_date,
    Items,
    stock,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Items ORDER BY arrival_date) as rn
  FROM
    future_stock
)
SELECT
  ci.transaction_date,
  ci.Items,
  GREATEST(ci.cumulative_inventory, 0) as inventory_sales,
  fsa.stock
FROM
  cumulative_inventory ci
LEFT JOIN
  future_stock_adjusted fsa ON ci.Items = fsa.Items AND ci.rn = fsa.rn;
```

The query will generate the **recursive inventory-sales** for each day until the arrival date is matched, and then the future stock will be added while keeping the sales updated accordingly. The `GREATEST` function ensures that the inventory_sales won't go below 0.